# Linear Color Gradient to items in HStack?

Tags: ios, swiftui, linear-gradients, hstack

Is there a way in SwiftUI to add a gradient color to all items in an HStack.

[image]

You can apply an individual Color to both the HStack `.background` and `.foregroundColor` But because LinearGradient is a struct that conforms to View you can't pass it to `.foregroundColor` because it is expecting a Color.

You can work round this in various ways (one example using opacity below) but I was curious with so many SwiftUI options if I was missing something else?

SwiftUI Example :

```
struct GradView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach((1...5).reversed(), id: \.self) { index in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .opacity(Double(index) / 5)
            }
        }.foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}
```

SwiftUI Output :

[image]

Comment: If you mean *built-in*, then no, but as you said *there are various ways* - what's wrong with your own? It is not clear from post what do you try to achieve.

Comment: With SwiftUI being new and my understanding being limited I just wanted to check if there was a built in method of doing the same. It would seem rolling your own is the way to go, much appreciated Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in Gradient... how to present it is up to us... Here is possible alternate, but it is just ... one of many other variants.. you know.

[image: demo]

```
struct GradView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach((1...7).reversed(), id: \.self) { index in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    Rectangle().fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                        .frame(width: 4, height: 50)
                }
            }
        }.background(LinearGradient(gradient: 
           Gradient(colors:[.red, .black]), 
                    startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
    }
}
```